# Can i use a fingerprint scanner to send a text value to a textarea/form?

Tags: php, web-applications, webforms, fingerprint, biometrics

I am looking to use a usb fingerprint scanner in a web application, which will be used to identify a user in the system.

I have used a USB barcode reader in the past and it passes the barcode number to any focussed text area, whether it be in a browser or a desktop application. I would like to know if I can use a fingerprint scanner in a similar way. I have no idea how the scanners work, but I am assuming they generate a unique code when a print is scanned.

So the way I would like it to work would be as follows once the scanner is plugged in and USB drivers are installed:

An existing user registers their fingerprint for the first time, the scanner creates a unique hash which is input into a text area and submitted to the server and saved in the db against the user. Next time the user scans their print the hash is submitted and the user can be identified by querying the db.

Can USB finger print scanners be used in this way and can I buy any USB scanner to achieve this? Is a £10 scanner less accurate than a £100 scanner?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are some out there which provide this functionality, just look for *password functionality* or something similar. If you find a model which you think does what you want just contact the shop-owner and tell him what you are looking for and if it can do what its supposed to do. I'm sure they will help you :)